# calculate logout time based on next person login sql server

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

Hi I am new to sql server , I have some data which contains information about telephone operator, telephone table and log in time .
sample data follows like this

```
telephone_operator telephone_table      log_in_time
user1              0302                 2014-10-08 09:06:00
user1              0302                 2014-10-08 12:07:00
user2              0302                 2014-10-08 10:10:00
user1              0302                 2014-10-08 13:30:00
user2              0302                 2014-10-08 11:03:00
user3              0308                 2014-10-08 11:03:00
user3              0308                 2014-10-08 13:20:00
```

I need to find the logout time for each user on telephone table for each event.

want the output like this

```
telephone_operator telephone_table      log_in_time             Logout_time
user1              0302                 2014-10-08 09:06:00      2014-10-08 10:10:00
user2              0302                 2014-10-08 10:10:00      2014-10-08 11:03:00 
user2              0302                 2014-10-08 11:03:00      2014-10-08 12:07:00
user1              0302                 2014-10-08 12:07:00      2014-10-08 13:30:00
user1              0302                 2014-10-08 13:30:00      NUll(or) 2111-11-11 00:00:00
user3              0308                 2014-10-08 11:03:00      2014-10-08 13:20:00
user3              0308                 2014-10-08 13:20:00      NUll(or) 2111-11-11 00:00:00
```

Here's is my current attempts at a solution:

```
SELECT [user], [table], [login] ,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
       (PARTITION BY [table] ORDER BY [login]) AS LoginOccurrenceSortedByDate 
INTO #loginlogout 
FROM [dbo].[2014Logindata] 

ALTER TABLE #loginlogout add logout smalldatetime
```

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this in any way? Do you have some SQL that isn't producing your desired output. It would be useful if you could show your efforts so far.

Comment: Hi Tanner Thankyou for editing my post. yeah I tried different sql queries and the close that I came to is

Comment: Add the SQL to the question rather than the comments. It's not easy to read in the comments.

Comment: As a general rule, you will always get a better response to your questions if you show your attempts at a solution, regardless how close they were to an actual solution.

Comment: SELECT [user], [table], [login] ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [table] ORDER BY [login]) AS LoginOccurrenceSortedByDate
     into #loginlogout FROM  [dbo].[2014Logindata] 
    
  alter table #loginlogout
     add logout smalldatetime

Comment: I've added it to the question for you this time, you just need to click `edit` and add it yourself in future.

Comment: @Tanner you are wonderful :) Ok, Thank you very much for all the inputs and help. Im kind of stressed and it was my first post so not able to read all the instructions. But Next time for sure  I will read all the instruction before I post and follow your tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  telephone_operator, 
  telephone_table, 
  log_in_time, 
  COALESCE((SELECT min(log_in_time) 
   FROM <tablename> 
   WHERE t1.log_in_time < log_in_time
      AND t1.telephone_table = telephone_table),'2111-11-11') as Logout_time
FROM <tablename> t1
```

Comment: Thank you  very much for your very quick reply. yeah It looks like It worked like a charm . the only thing i need to do is add another where condition in the subquerey  and **t1.telephone_table= telephone_table**

Comment: sorry , I didn't see the latest update. Yeah I was referring to the earlier post. Just double checking before I accept as an answer. Once again thank you very much it was a great help indeed